# Full Text Search Auto-Partition Schemes and Functions

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, partitioning

We have some full text searches running on our SQL Server 2012 Development (Enterprise) database. We noticed that partition schemes and functions are being (periodically) added to the DB. I can only assume that the partitions are for FTS as they have the following form:

Scheme:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [ifts_comp_fragment_data_space_46093FC3] AS PARTITION [ifts_comp_fragment_partition_function_46093FC3] TO ([FTS], [FTS], [FTS])
```

Function:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [ifts_comp_fragment_partition_function_46093FC3](varbinary(128)) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (0x00330061007A00660073003200360036, 0x0067006F00730066006F00720064)
```

The problem is that our production servers are running SQL Server 2012 Standard which does not support partitions. Thus it adds an extra admin burden on our schema compares (using SSDT) to exclude these partitions every time. When one does (inevitably) creep in it is a pain to remove. We have done some extensive research and have not been able to come up with any answer as to why this is even happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those are internal to the fulltext search functionality.  You have no control over them.

However, I would consider it a bug that they show up in your schema compares.  You'll never create/alter/drop them yourselves, and they completely maintained by sql server, so I would file a bug report on http://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think it is a bug if they show up in the schema compares in Visual Studio / SSDT as it has no way of knowing how they were created. Could you please
a) provide a little bit more info why this happens  and 
b) indicate whether we will be able to restore on Standard Edition even if these exist (as they are also created by Standard Edition which refuses to bring databases online that has partitions defined)

Comment: Fulltext indexing stores its data in several internal tables.  If the number of documents in your fulltext index is large enough, sql server may partition those tables.  The partition scheme and partition function are a result of that.  Sql won't always partition the internal tables, and I haven't seen any good documentation on this behavior.   I don't have a copy of standard edition to test restoring on, so I can't speak to, however, worst case is you restore and have to rebuild the ft catalog.

Comment: We have subsequently tested restores and they work. Where it all went wrong was that SQL Data Tools > Schema Compare would pick up the partitions and script them into the main shcema. SQL 2012 would then think that these partitions were created by a user (and not FTS) and thus refuse to restore on Standard. Thus we could work around this by being a bit more careful with our schema compares.